# Determining coefficient in geometric progression

Tags: c

For an assignment at Uni we had to code a program that takes numbers as input and determines the coefficient if they form a geometric progression once you declare EOF (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>). If the user inputs a number that doesn't belong to an already established progression the program breaks, telling us there's no geometric progression.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
int prevNum;
int Num;
scanf_s("%i", &prevNum);
scanf_s("%i", &Num);
int r = Num / prevNum;
prevNum = Num;
while ((scanf("%i", &Num) != EOF))
{
    if (Num / prevNum != r)
    {
        printf("No progression \n");
        return 0;
    }

    else prevNum = Num;


}
    printf("Progression with r=%i \n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

What I'd like to ask is whether there's a better, more practical way to fulfill the same task.

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` statement inside the `while` loop,
since the method returns when the condition is true,
you can drop the `else`.

In the condition of the `while`, you have pointless parentheses.

When printing stuff without variables,
I prefer `puts` instead of `printf` because it's shorter.

`scanf_s` doesn't compile with my compiler `gcc`.
I don't know what it is, but replacing with `scanf` seems to work fine for me.

Notice in your question that the syntax highlighter made `Num` have a different color from other variables.
It's because `CamelCase` is usually used for class names,
and `camelCase` for variable names.
So I'd rename this to `num`, or `thisNum` (to sort of harmonize with `prevNum`).

Pay attention to formatting. It makes the code more readable. For example:

- You didn't indent the `main` body, then after the `while` loop you indented.
- There are pointless blank lines in the `while` loop that just look strange.

With the above suggestions applied:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int prevNum;
    scanf("%i", &prevNum);
    int thisNum;
    scanf("%i", &thisNum);
    int r = thisNum / prevNum;
    prevNum = thisNum;
    while (scanf("%i", &thisNum) != EOF)
    {
        if (thisNum / prevNum != r)
        {
            puts("No progression");
            return 0;
        }
        prevNum = thisNum;
    }
    printf("Progression with r=%i \n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (`scanf_s` is a function in the Microsoft Visual Studio C runtime library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/w40768et.aspx. It is meant to be a "safe" version of `scanf()`.)

Answer (score 1):

You are performing integer division, which truncates the quotient. It is therefore entirely possible to have a non-geometric sequence be declared as a geometric sequence.

Also consider the degenerate cases.  What if there is only one input? Is that a geometric sequence? At the least, you should check the return value of `scanf_s()` to see if you actually got any input.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out implementing a check for only one input. Could you give me any hints?

Answer (score 0):

`while ((scanf("%i", &Num) != EOF))` is a potential infinite loop.

Should input consists of a non-integer, like "xyz", `scanf()` will return 0, the loop will continue using the old value of `Num`, possibly uninitialized.  Consider:

```
while ((scanf("%i", &Num) == 1))
```